# How to fix POST endpoint issue to allow node.js and express to work on live website (HostGator Shared)

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I'm getting into node.js and decided to create a user account management system using MySQL as the back-end. On LocalHost it is working fine. I then tried to replicate this on my live website. I installed nvm, npm, node and all the dependencies. Now, on local host all I have to do is "node login.js" and everything works. On the live website it is a different story. I cannot seem to figure out how to get the POST endpoints to work.

An example of this...

```html
 <form action="auth" method="POST">
```

should allow for this javascript to run

```js
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
```

On the HostGator terminal I have installed all my dependencies, also Apache is available on HostGator but I am not using it, should I?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.16.1",
    "express-sessions": "^1.0.6",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "nan": "^2.14.0"
```

I use "node login.js" to start the server

Here is my full code with some credentials **** out

HTML

```html
 <div class="accounts-form">
   <h1>Login Form</h1>
   <form action="auth" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required maxlength="50">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required maxlength="255">
    <input type="submit">
    <a href="/signup"><h4> Sign Up </h4></a>
   </form>
  </div>
```

JavaScript

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const saltRounds = 14;

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 **********
});

var app = express();

app.use(session({
  secret: ****************,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
});

app.post('/user', function(request, response) {

  var username = request.body.username;
  var password = request.body.password;
  var password2 = request.body.password2;
  var email = request.body.email;

  if (password == password2) {
    if (username && password && email) {
      bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(error, hash) {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ?)";
        connection.query(sql, [username, hash, email], function(error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
          console.log("1 record inserted");
          response.redirect('/login');
        })
      });
    };
  } else {
    console.log("Password not identical.");
  };
});

app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
  var username = request.body.username;
  var password = request.body.password;

  if (username && password) {
    connection.query('SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?', [username], function(error, hash) {
      bcrypt.compare(password, hash[0].password, function(error, res) {
        if (res) {
          request.session.loggedin = true;
          request.session.username = username;
          response.redirect('/home');
        } else {
          response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
        }
        response.end();
      });
    });
  } else {
    response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
    response.end();
  }
});

app.get('/signup', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/signup.html'));
});

app.get('/login', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
});

app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
  if (request.session.loggedin) {
    response.send('Welcome back, ' + request.session.username + '!');
  } else {
    response.send('Please login to view this page!');
  }
  response.end();
});

app.listen(3742);
```

It is resulting in a 404 error whenever I hit the submit button
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lroid.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/auth" method="POST">
```

because you defined and not auth

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: look at the action tag of your form there you call **auth** after not **/auth** like it should be. as an example Like in **<a href="/signup">** it would call **/signup** and not **signup** .